# Why would a dirty read of a table cause WRITELOG waits in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm running into an interesting issue in production, which I cannot replicate in our QA/Staging environments.

I have a query that is doing dirty reads on a fairly large table (around 6 million rows, but we only keep the last 90 days of data in it, older records are warehoused in a different database). This table has lots of writes to it, as it logs page views, but only occasionally is data read from the table.

Recently I noticed that when one specific query is running, SQL Server 2019 starts generating a ton of WRITELOG waits and appears to hold up any other requests that are trying to write to the database.

Now the query itself has `nolock` hints on all the tables, because it's okay if dirty data is returned. We use the `nolock` hints because the writes to the table are extremely frequently and queries to this table can be slow because there are a lot of page scans required.

The query itself looks something like this:

```
select
        clt.ViewDate, clt.UserId, clt.RemoteAddress, clt.LibraryId, clt.Parameters
    , u.Fullname
    , cl.Id as VideoId, cl.Title
    -- we need a compound key for each row, so we can count the unique rows
    , case 
        when clt.ViewDate is null then null 
        else row_number() over (order by clt.ViewDate, clt.UserId, clt.LibraryId, clt.Parameters) 
    end as compoundKey
from
    ContentLibrary as cl (nolock)
        left join
    (
        ContentLibraryTracking as clt (nolock)
            inner join
        [User] as u (nolock)
            on
        clt.UserId = u.UserId
    )
        on
    clt.ViewDate between @startDate and @endDate
        and
    clt.Parameters like @filter

where
    1 = 1
and
    cl.ContentType = @contentType

order by
    clt.ViewDate
```

The problem table appears to be the `ContentLibraryTracking`. This is the table that has millions of rows and has lots of inserts and we warehouse rows nightly, so there can be a lot of page fragmentation. We do defrag the indices and stats weekly on the table.

When this query is running, `sp_BlitzWho` will report the query has entered into a `CXCONSUMER`. I will then see SQL Server 2019 starting to queue processes with a `WRITELOG` wait. This processed remain in this state until the query has finished running.

Since our application has some kind of write transaction with every page view, this means this query is holding up execution for entire application, which is obviously bad.

While I know have page scans is bad for a query plan, the query requires searching patterns in a `varchar` column, which is why the page scans happen. Since the reads are very infrequently, the table is optimized for writes since those are extremely frequent. And while the query could perform better, considering the work it's doing even when it's slow it runs within 15 seconds or so.

One thing I do see from the `sp_BlitzWho` results is the query is using parallelism and it also states the Transaction Isolation Level is `Read Committed` (which I would unexpected `Read Uncommitted` since all the tables have a `nolock` hint).

What would cause a query with dirty reads to be forcing the database to queue up `WRITELOG` events?

I could see this happening if the query was altering data and causing it's own transaction log entries, but that should not be happening with the query. That's the whole reason we are using the `nolock` hint on the tables.

Also, our database, log files and tempdb are all on their own logical storage devices, so reads from the database should not be causing a IO problems writing to the transaction log files.

A couple of notes on the environment:

- We are running Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8-GDR) (KB4583459) - 15.0.4083.2 (X64))
- The database is running in a VM
- We backup transaction logs every 5 minutes (could this be the issue?)
- Memory and CPU usage appear fine with the query runs
- SQL Monitor 11 only really shows spikes in the log flushes and waits (which would match the behavior). Page splits, buffer cache & page are all normal. I do see the "disk read bytes/sec" go up on the logic drive that has the database on it, but the writes on all drives (including the transaction logs) look okay.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated as I'm really scratching my head over this issue.

Comment: Note that snapshot may be a better option than read uncommitted or nolock. The latter may result in data missed or duplicated. I suspect the WRITELOG waits are not related to nolock, but rather a side-affect of the resource-intensive select query. Are your log files physically isolated from data files?

Comment: @DanGuzman 

Thanks for the input. Is there a word for when you answer your own question right after posting it?

Your comment about it being a resource intensive query appears to be write on the mark. Right after I posted my question I started looking at the ```sp_BlitzWho``` results in more detail. I noticed the parallelism was using *all* the CPUs. 

So I changed the MAXDOP to half the CPU/cores and this appears to have resolved the issue. I'm going to keep monitoring the situation, but looks like an instance where the MAXDOP was not set correctly.

Comment: Most likely the writes are actually in `tempdb` because of hash or sort spills, you could share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan and we can see if it can be optimized. The isolation level is the main isolation level, not the one for each individual table. You also need to understand more about `NOLOCK` (aka `READ UNCOMMITTED`) it can cause *completely* erroneous data to come out (duplicated rows, missing rows, entire duplicate or missing pages) because of page splits and rows moving about underneath you. `SNAPSHOT` would be much, much better

Comment: If you are going to use hints, at least use the current (not deprecated) syntax!

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted my question I started looking at the `sp_BlitzWho` results in more detail. I noticed the parallelism was using all the CPUs. So I changed the `MAXDOP` to half the CPU/cores and this appears to have resolved the issue. I'm going to keep monitoring the situation, but looks like an instance where the `MAXDOP` was not set correctly.

It make sense that if a query is eating up all the available cores, that other threads would be waiting. I was just thrown off by the `WRITELOG` waits.